# Reusing header sections in tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, header

I've been searching the whole WWW for a decent solution, but most seem outdated or insufficient.

I'm struggling in simply reusing a custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView in my UITableViewController.

This is my approach:

1. Create a nib.
2. Create a custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`, named `HeaderView`
3. Add a label and connect it to `HeaderView`
4. Register the nib in `UITableViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()`
5. Dequeue and return the nib in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int)`

Custom `HeaderView` class:

```
class HeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    @IBOutlet weak var customLabel: UILabel!
}
```

In `UITableViewController` class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "HeaderView", bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "Header")

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "Header") as! HeaderView
    headerView.customLabel.text = "This is a header section"
    return headerView
}
```

This seems to be the approach advised by many, but I believe I'm unable to properly set the nib's owner custom class to `HeaderView` (`UITableViewHeaderFooterView`). When the cell is dequeued I get a fatal crash:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x60000020ebe0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key customLabel.'`

I'm definitely sure I've connected the UILabel correctly to File's Owner in nib IB.

[image: Assigning class]

I tried changing the `HeaderView` class to `UIView`, but then `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "Header") as! HeaderView` would result in a crash when forcing UITableViewHeaderFooterView to UIView.

Why is this, and what is the current way in solving this?

Comment: but I'm unable to set the nib's owner custom class to HeaderView (UITableViewHeaderFooterView). ?

Comment: Updated answer with screenshot!

Comment: In your screen shot Inheritance from target should be checked  Pl Check Your HeaderView.swift is added to target -> tap on swift file -> Right panel check target is selected or not

Comment: Yes, I noticed it wasn't checked in the screenshot by mistake, it does inherit the model from target actually

Comment: you forgot to connect customLabel it explicitly saying that

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue was that I set the nib - File's owner to `HeaderView` and connected my `customLabel` to that.

The solution was to set the nib's view class to `HeaderView` and connect the label to that instead. It was also oddly necessary to put it inside a UIView.

[image: as such]